# Add class to <img>-tag generated by knitr (Rmd)

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I write a R Notebook (Rmd) that I want to render as HTML.

````
    ::: { .mycls }

    ```{r dev="svg", fig.dim=c(8,6), out.width="100%"}
    ggplot(data.frame(x=rnorm(40, 5, 8),
                      y=rnorm(40, 2, 1),
                      group=factor(sample(c(1,2), 40, TRUE, c(0.3, 0.7))))) +
    geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color=group))
    ```
    :::
````

The corresponding html snippet looks like this *(no working example!, truncated!)*:

```
<div class="mycls">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button type="button" ...>
        <span>Show</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse r-code-collapse" id="rcode-643E0F362">
    <pre class="r">
      <code class="hljs">... the code from above ...</code>
    </pre>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,<...>" width="100%">
  </p>
</div>
```

I want to add functionality to the figure (`<img>`-tag) with JS and CSS, so it would be great, to have a class on it. The closest thing I found was adding the

```
::: { .mycls }

:::
```

to create the enclosing `<div class="mycls>`-tag. Then I could search for the `<img>`-tag within. However I'd prefer a solution, where I can have the class-attribute set directly in the `<img>`-tag.

I was trying to add options to the chunk:

````
```{r dev="svg", fig.dim=c(8,6), out.width="100%", class.img="imgcls", fig.class="imgcls"} 
   ...
```
````

since it seems like, you could specify tons of attributes there, but I didn't find the right one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct [chunk option](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#plots) is `out.extra` (bad naming, I admit), e.g., `out.extra = 'class="mycls"'`.